# How to access VSTS work items from testing code which running on V2.x VSTS agent?

Tags: azure-devops

We run our E2E automation test on build agent (V1.105.xxx) after the build is successfully. The test code leverage Visual studio Unit Test framework to access VSTS work items to load test data using data driven approach (each test case method linked to one test case work item):

[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.Tes‌​tCase","https://myaccount.vi‌​sualstudio.com/Defau‌​ltCollection;MyProje‌​ct";, "1111111", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)

And we run our V1.x build agent in interactive mode with PAT auth as follows:

***C:\agent\agent\VsoAgent.exe /Login:e2etest,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;AuthType=PAT***

But we could not find a way run V2.x agent with PAT auth so as to access the VSTS work items.

Is it still supported in V2.x agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When use PAT to configure build agent, the PAT token is used only for the initial configuration of the agent. More information, you can refer to [Communication](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/agents#communication).

Regarding interactive mode, it will prompt the login window to let you authentication when configure or run build agent if the cached account can’t access vsts or there isn’t cached account. You need to change the permission for this user.

You can try to set Read permission to deny for this user in Version Control admin page, the queue build that need to download that source and check the result, the build will not start anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your point. Do you mean for V2.x agent, if I run "run.cmd" command, it will prompt the login window, and it also support PAT auth type?

Comment: @Youxu No, it will prompt the login window if no valid cached credential when run "run.cmd" command. The PAT that used in configure agent is just for configuration. Also for V1.XXX, [the credentials are used to perform the pool administration changes and are not used later by the agent too](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v1-windows#command-line-parameters).

Comment: Thanks! I resolved the issue by running the V2.x agent service using local admin account. (before, I run it using local service account)

Comment: sure:) Before I summarize the solution in new reply, could you help me understand why running agent using local admin works? Does agent registration store the PAT token somewhere, and the local admin account use that token to access VSTS work items? BTW: we leverage Visual studio's UT framework to write the data driven test case,
 example:
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase","https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection;MyProject", "1111111", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

Comment: @Youxu The credential can be cached for current user when access to VSTS. So you need to connect to VSTS first, then run the driven test under the same account and it will use cached credential to access the resource.

Comment: so, regarding the access to VSTS from testing code, it is nothing related to the PAT token I used when registering the agent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149199/discussion-between-youxu-and-starain-msft).

Answer (score 0):

Summarize the issue and solution:

Per starain's comments, in old V1.x agent, regarding the access to VSTS work items from our testing code, it is nothing related to the PAT token we used to run the agent in interactive mode. Actually we run the agent using local admin account of the VM, which we ever used to connect to VSTS, and the credential was cached. The testing code just used that cached credential to access VSTS work items.

So the solution for V2.x is simple, just run the agent service using the local admin account. No need to run in interactive mode.

Thanks starain's great help!